# setting python for loop iterator during iteration

Tags: python, for-loop

How do I change a python iterator mid iteration?

For example:

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
    i = 5
```

This prints:

```
0
1
...
9
```

I would like to print:

```
0
5
5
5
...
```

EDIT: Sorry this question came out as confusing to people. I was interested in why when I try to change an iterator during a for loop the for loop ignores it on the next iteration.

Someone else has already submitted an answer that clears my confusion. range creates a list and then the for loop assigns the iterator to the next variable in the list.

Comment: If you change `i` in the loop it's not going to terminate. Even if it did - you are doing something **conceptually** wrong.

Comment: I realize this hence my output bring 5, 5, 5, ... as in repeating. My real code will only change the iterator inside of a condition so it can skip unnecessary data.

Comment: Why don't you tell us [the problem you're trying to solve instead of the problem your attempted solution is causing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: You should tell us your actual problem, as @TigerhawkT3 said. Because while you can get the desired output that you show in your question with `for x in ([0] + [5]*9): print x`, or even just `print '\n'.join(['0'] + ['5']*9)`, I don't think that's going to help with your actual problem :).

Comment: I am more interested in how python's for loops is implemented than fixing my current problem. Cody presented an answer which explains how the for loop works though. I can see how it is confusing for others though so I will edit my original post to reflect what I am interested in.

Comment: I deleted my comment that was attributing a different answer to Cody than the one he actually posted; whoops :P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop is iterating over every number in the list created by range. You can change i for a given iteration, but the for loop just goes to the next number in the list. I think a while loop would be a different story, it actually uses the current value of i

Answer (score 1):

Following your response what you're trying to do already exists in the form of `continue`. It lets you skip an iteration by checking a certain condition holds:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i >= 5:
        continue # go to next iteration
    print i
```

Assuming you're using an iterator and not a list you can skip one element at a time, so a jump to a given index is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

To echo Cody Braun, see the following code and output:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i >= 5:
        i = 5
    print i
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
5
5
5
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class that was iterable and modify the iteration in the for-loop:

```
>>> class MyRange:
...     def __init__(self, stop):
...         self.current = 0 
...         self.stop = stop
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return self
...     def next(self): # Python 3: def __next__(self)
...         if self.current >= self.stop:
...             raise StopIteration
...         else:
...             self.current += 1
...             return self.current - 1 
...
>>> for i in MyRange(3):
...     print i
...
0
1
2
>>> r = MyRange(10)
>>> for i in r:
...     print i
...     r.current += 1
...
0
2
4
6
8
>>> r = MyRange(10)
>>> for i in r:
...     print i
...     r.current = 5
0
5
5
5
5
5
# and so on...
```